# extract a substring from a string in smalltalk (squeak)

Tags: oop, smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to extract a substring from a string which would be the substring in between 2 delimiters
i.e it should be defined as follows:

```
substring: aString delimiter: aDelimiter
```

and, for an example, if i'll get this line:

```
substring: 'dddd#sss#dddd' delimiter: '#'
```

the function should return 'sss'.

this is what i've been trying, which didn't work:

```
substring: aString delimiter: aDelimiter
|index temp1 temp2 sz arr str|
      arr := aString asArray.
      sz := arr size.
      index := arr lastIndexOf: aDelimiter.
      temp1 := arr first: (sz - index +1).
      index := temp1 lastIndexOf: aDelimiter.
      sz :=temp1 size.
      temp2 := temp1 first: (sz - index).
      str := temp2 asString.
      ^str.
```

I don't know if it's worth mentioning but it's supposed to be a class method.

Comment: What is your code doing? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 4):

Your basic problem is that the argument aDelimiter is a string instead of a character.  You want to call it with $# instead of '#'.

Now for some easier ways. Probably the easiest is to use the subStrings: method:

```
('dddd#sss#dddd' subStrings: '#') at: 2
```

This has the disadvantage that it extracts the entire string into substrings separated by the # character which may be more than you need.

The next easiest option is to use streams:

```
'dddd#sss#dddd' readStream upTo: $#; upTo: $#
```

That code only extracts the part that you need.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't far from working code, as David pointed out. But I'd just like to point out that it's very procedural. A lot of the magic of Smalltalk, and OOP in general, is writing beautiful, easy to understand code that sends intention revealing messages to a community of appropriate objects. This includes leaning on the objects already existing in the image. I can't think of a time when I've had to go this low level for a simple task like this. It would be great to read one of the many awesome OOP references. My favorite is [A Mentoring Course on Smallalk](http://www.lulu.com/us/en/shop/andres-valloud/a-mentoring-course-on-smalltalk/paperback/product-3788890.html)

I think David's solution is right on. I personally like `second` instead of `at: 2`, but it feels picky and might be personal preference `('dddd#sss#dddd' subStrings: '#') second`

Comment: I like ```second``` as well.  It's clearer than ```at: 2```.  It's not in all Smalltalk dialects but it's easy to add.

Answer (score 2):

While I like both of the answers above, you might also want to consider another that is closer to your initial attempt and is a little bit more efficient than the others in that it only creates the object you are looking for (e.g., no intermediate Stream)

```
substringOf: aString delimitedBy: aCharacter
    | i j |
    i := aString indexOf: aCharacter.
    j := aString indexOf: aCharacter startingAt: i + 1.
    ^aString copyFrom: i + 1 to: j - 1
```

(Note b.t.w. that I'm also suggesting a slightly different selector.)

Another aspect you would like to consider is how the method should react if `aCharacter` is not in `aString`, it is only once or it has three or more occurrences. Something in the lines of:

```
substringOf: aString delimitedBy: aCharacter
    | i j |
    i := aString indexOf: aCharacter.
    i = 0 ifTrue: [^''].
    j := aString indexOf: aCharacter startingAt: i + 1.
    j = 0 ifTrue: [^''].
    ^aString copyFrom: i + 1 to: j - 1
```

But again, if performance is not a concern in your case, then go for the readStream upTo upTo answer, as it is probably the best.